# Angular 5-Google Maps Search Bar

Tags: angular, google-maps, searchbar

I am new on Angular and I just started to developing an Angular web application using with google maps. I need to put a searchbar for autocomplate when start to write typing it should already starts to show most meaningful places. I have used some ready libraries like "@types/googlemaps" but it is not matching correctly on searching some places. Also I know google have an API for "Places search box" but it is for JavaScript. 
My question:
-Is there any opportunity to use GoogleMaps Javascript API's in Angular 5 ?

Comment: You can write javascript code in Angular 5.
So, include Google Map's JavaScript API library in your project. 
How to include Google Map's JavaScript API library?
Ans: 1. Add the JS library URL to  `script` array in `angular-cli.json`.
        2. Add the `script` tag in the `index.html`.

If you are using variables of Google Map library in service or components, declare them as below
  `declare var VARIABLE_NAME;`

Answer (score 1):

You can write javascript code in Angular 5.
So, include Google Map's JavaScript API library in your project.

How to include Google Map's JavaScript API library?

Ans: 1. Add the JS library URL to  `script` array in `angular-cli.json`.

2. Add the `script` tag in the `index.html`.

If you are using variables of Google Map library in service or components, declare them as below

```
declare var VARIABLE_NAME;
declare var map;  // e.g. for map variable.
```

Comment: Hi Basavaraj , 
Thank you for your answer.However I have added  
"scripts": [
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"
      ],

and on index page 

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MyKEyHere&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>

still when i worked "ng serve" comment on cmd I am getting this error: 

recording Error:ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Deniz\D1\src/https:\maps.googleapis.com\maps\api\js'

Comment: @DenizBayar

 Point 1: You can either add script in script array in angular-cli.json **OR** add the script in index.html


Point 2: You need to add the proper URL in the script tag.
 i.e. 

   `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js" async defer></script>`

Comment: Thank you Basavaraj, I have add the google maps api's on my index field. However I couldn't work my code it is because of something else. But I got my answer and learned how to work wirh external js libraries. Thanks a lot for your interest !